# 2007 V6 Mercury Milan Premier key stuck

Tags: key, fuse, mercury, ignition-key, milan

Alright so I have a Milan that was given to me from my grandfather, he never had problems with the key getting stuck until I turned it on after a month.

The key gets stuck all the time now no matter which side I insert it,
The shifter does get stuck nor does and functions 
It actually works normal, just the key stays in 
I tried shifting from park to drive and turn the wheel to see if the key pops out but no luck 
A mechanic told me it's a brake fuse gone bad 
Another told me the ignition switch fuse is bad 
I don't know what to do or how to fix it?
In order for to me to take the key out I have to disconnect the battery and it pops out like nothing...
Anyone understand why it's doing this to me?

If you want specs
It's a V6, with 126k miles on it

Comment: I don't know about your Mecury, but some of them have a little sensor on the right side of the shifter to let the car know when it's in park.  Occasionally, one of the clips comes unpopped, and all that is required is popping it back in.